# Authorization Error -- Contact your Security Administrator

Tags: peoplesoft

The Peoplesoft Database, Application Server, and Web Server are up and running.

Unable to login to PIA as `VP1` because of `Authorization Error -- Contact your Security Administrator`.

Below are the Application Server Logs:

```
PSAPPSRV.10180 (26) [2020-02-04T01:49:30.513 GetCertificate] z9skwzRuICAUWA 3282132548821545985 - (3) Returning context. ID=VP1, Lang=ENG, UStreamId=014930507_10180.26, Token=PSFT_EP/2020-02-03-17.49.30.000001/VP1/ENG/nE8KiNyFebhVeORMN7uI+lf5Xwo=
PSMONITORSRV.15420 [2020-02-04T02:21:55.691] - - - (2) (PerfMon Agent) Registered successfully
PSAPPSRV.10180 (29) [2020-02-04T02:58:16.275 GetCertificate] wLjLvrMO3yG3uQ 2085807486657797121 - (3) Returning context. ID=VP1, Lang=ENG, UStreamId=025816275_10180.29, Token=PSFT_EP/2020-02-03-18.58.16.000000/VP1/ENG/uXTGd2i5x206untuoiqPMRHPfgQ=
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually get that error message when the users does not have any roles.  Ensure that VP1 has roles assigned to it.

if you have database access, the following SQL may help:

```
-- Check if they have roles
select * from PSROLEUSER where ROLEUSER = 'VP1'

-- Check to see what permission lists the roles assigned to the user grant them.
select * from PSOPRCLS where OPRID = 'VP1'
```

Comment: Hi I ran both the queries and VP1 has 204 Permission lists assigned and 197 roles assigned.